# Generating HTML from JSON, assigning click events but not working on initial div

Tags: javascript, json

Bad title, wasn't too sure how to describe.

Please take a look at the following object, you can see that there are 4 key's called `data-click`. When generating the HTML from this JSON object these keys are being added as attributes correctly.

However for some reason when I do a `querySelectorAll` search on the HTML object it is only finding 3 of these attributes, why is this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzovPE

```js
var json = `{
  "div": {
    "id": "marvLightbox",
    "data-click": "EventClose",
    "0": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__left",
        "data-click": "EventLeft"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "div": {
        "class": "marvLightbox__right",
        "data-click": "EventRight"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "div": {
        "0": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__eschint",
            "content": "Press <span>ESC</span> to close"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "div": {
            "class": "marvLightbox__close",
            "data-click": "EventClose"
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "img": {
            "src": "https://www.asphaltandrubber.com/wp-content/gallery/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-with-jensen-beeler/ducati-1199-panigale-r-launch-cota-jensen-beeler-07.jpg",
            "class": "responsive-img image"
          }
        },
        "class": "marvLightbox"
      }
    }
  }
}`;

function buildHTML(code) {
  "use strict";

  var handleAttribute = function(element, attribute, value) {
    if (value instanceof HTMLElement) {
      return element.appendChild(value);
    }

    switch (attribute) {
      case 'class':
      case 'src':
      case 'id':
      case 'data-click':
        return element.setAttribute(attribute, value);
      case 'content':
        return element.innerHTML = value;
        // other keys...
      default:
        console.log(element.tagName, attribute, value);
                     }
  }
  var htmlReviver = function(key, value) {
    // parse as element
    if (isNaN(key) && typeof value === 'object') {
      var element = document.createElement(key);
      var subValue;

      for (var attribute in value) {
        handleAttribute(element, attribute, value[attribute]);
      }

      return element;
      // move element from { index: { tagName: Element } } to { index: Element }
    } else if (!isNaN(key)) {
      return value[Object.keys(value)[0]];
      // leave property alone
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

  try {
    var htmlObject = JSON.parse(code, htmlReviver);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('marv.lightbox (Error): The HTML structure provided appears to have an error: ' + e);
  }

  return htmlObject;
}

(function() {
  var html = buildHTML(json);
  
  html.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener('click', function() { events(e.dataset.click); });
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML += 'Function: ' + e.dataset.click + ' Element: ' + e + '<br>';
  });
  
  document.getElementById('test').append(html);
}());
```

```css
body > div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id='debug'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Edit 1:

Right, this isn't making sense. If I append the `html` object to my div, the same way I do in the above example. And then if I do a `querySelectorAll` search on the content within the div I appended the HTML to, it then see's all 4 `data-click` attributes...

```
(function() {
  var html = buildHTML(json);
  document.getElementById('test').append(html);

  document.getElementById('test').querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML += 'Function: ' + e.dataset.click + ' Element: ' + e + '<br>';
  });
}());
```

It SHOULD do exactly the same thing with the actual `html` object though as it's the SAME content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is in the `querySelectorAll` part.  I added an `alert(html.innerHTML)` to your codepen at line 103, as a quick way to see what the html looked like, that had been built.  That `html` variable only contains three "data-click" attributes, so it looks like the problem is in the generation of those html attributes.

It looks like it's not handling the first `data-click`, which also looks like it's in a different place in the json structure, so that may be why it's being ignored.

### Edit

Hmm, it is odd, although now, I'm seeing the reverse of what you're seeing, i.e. I can see four data-click attributes in "test", and three in "debug".[image]

I'm not sure if that's the structure you were expecting, but it does seem to have added the four div tags correctly with the correct data-click attrributes.

Comment: Really struggling to figure out why isn't not handling that first `data-click`, any ideas? I have put console.log's within the `htmlReviver` etc and it seems to be adding the attribute etc...